# Microsoft Edge in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, microsoft-edge

I use PhpStorm as my editor. I want to be able to add Microsoft Edge browser to PhpStorm but just can't get it to work.

As anyone been able to setup Microsoft Edge to work in PhpStorm?

Comment: Where do you want it to use and how did you configure PhpStorm for that? Screenshots are welcome.

Comment: PHPStorm can be setup using different browsers to view what your sode looks like. The problem is that you have to map to an .exe file like iexplore.exe by when using Edge there is no .exe file. You have to lunch it by this %windir%\explorer.exe shell:Appsfolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge when I try in PHPStorm it does not work.

Comment: I see. Right now I may only suggest to: 1) create .cmd/.bat file that will launch the Edge browser and use it when specifying browser in PhpStorm 2) submit feature request ticket at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI

Comment: @LazyOne : good trick, perhaps gehrenfeld confirm or not resolving issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JetBrains got back to me and told me their engineers worked on it and could not get it to work.
They ask me to submit it as a future feature so I did.

Answer (score 1):

Under Tools > Web Browsers enter microsoft-edge: for the path. This is working for me.

[Open in Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3spT8.png)

Comment: That opens Edge, but doesn't open the current file/page; just a blank window

Comment: Didn't work for me, even after browsing to/entering the full path to the exe: `C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

I use

### https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/edge-launcher

just add the edge item in phpstorm\settings\browser and link to this .exe.

Comment: For me, this doesn't seem to hook up phpstorm's javascript debugger - breakpoints aren't hit in .js files referenced by the launched page. So I do primary debugging with Chrome, then use Edge Developer Tools from Microsoft to debug Edge-specific problems. (Thank goodness this will soon be a non-issue: Edge Chromium Beta uses V8 Javascript, and runs my pages just like Chrome - unlike Edge 18.)